# Format text output for XLS import

Tags: php

I have a db table with user data. One of the columns contains comments. I am trying to format my data to pass to a class for output in XLS and CSV. Every field is working great but when it comes to comments I am having the hardest time to get it to work in XLS. I was able to make it work in CSV output by stripping all line breaks and encoding HTML characters:

```
$comm = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $tx->comm));
```

What can I possibly do to make it work with XLS???

Comment: in what way does it "not work" ??

Comment: When I open Excel, comments column is blank.

Comment: need to see an example of the text

Comment: how on earth are we supposed to know why your comments are coming up blank in your spreadsheet when you have provided no code for how those comments got there in the first place, example data, etc..

Comment: It's a text input from textarea. I just hard-coded my original post for a test. When I put this much: "I have a db table with user data. One of the columns contains comments. I am trying to format my data to pass to a class for output in XLS and CSV. Every field is working great but when it comes to comments I am having the hardest time to get it to work in XLS. I was able to make it work in CSV output by stripping all line breaks and encoding HTML characters:" IT IS BLANK, but when I put only up to: "...XLS and CSV." IT"S THERE... I wonder if there's a char limit?..